# How does jQuery dynamic content work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, interactive

I don't know if that's what it's called but I'm trying to make some kind of interactive page that changes content based on a series of questions that the user can answer with "Yes" or "No".
Here's a simplified version of the code for better understanding.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <h1>Some question?</h1>
            <h2 id="yes" role="button">Yes</h2>
            <h2 id="no" role="button">No</h2>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var question = $("h1");
    var yes = $("#yes");
    var no = $("#no");

    $(yes).click(function() {
        question.text("Some text. Some other question?");
    });

    $(yes).click(function() {
        question.text("Different text. Different question?")
    });

});
```

Now what I want to do is: If the user's answer to the first question (the one in the HTML) was "yes" then it would display the second question (the first one in jQuery) and if his answer to that was "yes" it'd display the next question and so on. But what it does is just jump to the last question specified in jQuery when the user clicks "yes".

How do I control that? Is that the wrong way to go about what I'm trying to achieve? I'm a noob so sorry if not making much sense.

Edit: Now how do I write an if statement that will `$("<img src="#">).appendTo(container);`when the user reaches the third question?

Comment: Assuming you're going to have multiple divs, each with their own "yes" and "no" buttons, you can't use `id="yes"`. Only one element on the page can have a particular `id`.

Comment: What you're asking about is not called jQuery chaining.  That term applies to something else completely.  You are just asking about how you would make a dynamic page based on the user's actions.

Comment: It's only one div. Here's a [gif](http://i.imgur.com/Zjeyuzg.gifv) of the page.

Comment: just an observation ... `$(yes)` is like doing `$($("#yes"))` - which probably works, but is redundant ... you can use `yes.click(...` (like you did with `question` for example)

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks, didn't notice that at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var question = $("h1");
    var yes = "#yes";
    var no = "#no";
    var questions = [
                      "Some text. Some other question?",
                      "Different text. Different question?"
                    ];

    $(yes).click(function() {
        if(count == 2){
            $("<img src='#'>").appendTo(container);
        }
        question.text(questions[count]);
        count++;
    });   
});
```

Try this code.

When u call

```
$(yes).click(function() {
        question.text("Some text. Some other question?");
    });

$(yes).click(function() {
        question.text("Different text. Different question?")
    });
```

After executing the first `$(yes).click`, it continues to execute the 2nd `$(yes).click`, hence the issue you are facing.

My suggested approach is to put populate all ur "questions" into an array, and then use an index *count* to populate the `<h1>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Another way for doing this :
All the questions are already on the page, but hidden (except the first). That's not real dynamic content, but achieve the same result.
Notice how user values can be stored then send.

```js
function storeResponse(id_question,value){
    $('#result'+id_question).val(value);
    $('#container'+id_question).addClass("hidden");
    if (id_question<4){
        $('#container'+(id_question+1)).removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
       $('#results').submit();
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1"  class="container">
            <h1>1 Some question?</h1>
            <h2 id="yes" onclick="storeResponse(1,1)" role="button">Yes</h2>
            <h2 id="no" onclick="storeResponse(1,0)" role="button">No</h2>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="container hidden" >
            <h1>2 Some question?</h1>
            <h2 id="yes" onclick="storeResponse(2,1)" role="button">Yes</h2>
            <h2 id="no" onclick="storeResponse(2,0)" role="button">No</h2>
</div>
<div id="container3" class="container hidden">
            <h1>3 Some question?</h1>
            <h2 id="yes" onclick="storeResponse(3,1)"role="button">Yes</h2>
            <h2 id="no" onclick="storeResponse(3,0)" role="button">No</h2>
</div>
<div id="container4" class="container hidden">
            <h1>4 Some question?</h1>
            <h2 id="yes" onclick="storeResponse(4,0)" role="button">Yes</h2>
            <h2 id="no" onclick="storeResponse(4,0)" role="button">No</h2>
</div>

<form id="results" action="..." method="...">
<input type="hidden" id="result1" name="result1"  value="">
<input type="hidden" id="result2" name="result1"  value="">
<input type="hidden" id="result3" name="result1"  value="">
<input type="hidden" id="result4" name="result1"  value="">
</form>
```